# Build deep learning model for non-image data

Tags: matrix, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

Can you please tell me how to build an autoencoder using CNN and pooling layers, with a single matrix(4,4) with integer numbers?
e.g,
`input data = array([[ 4,  3,  8,  6], [ 1,  1,  2,  2], [24, 18, 32, 24], [ 6,  6,  8,  8]])`
`autoencoder(data)`
`output data= array([[ 4,  3,  8,  6], [ 1,  1,  2,  2], [24, 18, 32, 24], [ 6,  6,  8,  8]])`
Explanation:
https://medium.com/machine-learning-researcher/auto-encoder-d942a29c9807

Comment: Hi ! Is there a question in your post ?

Comment: Hi Yoan, I wan to build an autoencoder using cnn and pooling but I am new to deep learning can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The article you quoted is already well detailed, all you need to do is replaced `linear` units by `convolution` and `max pool` in the encoding part and `deconvolution` and `upsampling` in the decoding part.

[Here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/autoencoder/) is in example using Keras of a convolutional autoencoder.

But if you're new to Deep Learning I would not advise you to start here. Autoencoder are tricky, the expected output you described above could easily be obtained by setting:

```
def autoencoder(x):
    return x
```

Which is not something you want.

People commonly design "undercomplete" autoencoders, with internal layer of smaller dimension to induce some compression. But "overcomplete" autoencoders with larger internal dimension are also valid architecture combined with regularization.

Comment: I did the same as suggested by you, since I am using 2D matrix as my input data I reshape it first to (4,4,1) to convert it into a greyscale image.
 It is showing an error now: 
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 4, 4, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4, 4, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 4, 1, 1)

Comment: @aadilgani, it means your reshape is not correct since the model receive: `(None, 4, 1, 1)` instead of `(None, 4, 4, 1)`.